# Show svg hosted by a local server in Google Sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to show a locally hosted image in a google sheet.

Simply using `=Image('http://this.is.local/image.svg')` does not work, as the image will be loaded through Google Image cache proxy.
As the local server is not accessible by Google Image proxy server the picture is not shown. The help on `Image` also clearly states that this is not possible.

However, I still like to achieve somehow to show the locally hosted image somehow in the sheet. Are there solutions to somehow bypass the image cache and show the local image in the google sheet or is there another workaround to show a locally hosted image in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, this is not possible and there are no workarounds. Google Sheets is able to fetch data only if they are public and not behind a login. if you need to import local image you will need to do it via
 **Insert** > **Image** > **Upload**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there is one exception. If you are a g suite customer you can add a domain to a whitelist. Read this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041?hl=en